# p element stuck to divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a super weird problem.  Probably caused by something stupid in my HTML or CSS. I'm learning javascript currently, and I'm making a super simple webpage that demonstrates the dragging ability of javascript.  I have two divs, one that floats left and one right, and a p element that should be below the divs.  The problem is, I can't separate them.  The border of the p element extends into the divs for some reason.  I've tried messing with the height of the p element, but then the border isn't even around the text—it's in the divs. I've also tried separating them with margin-top on the p element and that brings the divs down with it.  So the elements seem stuck together and I truly don't know why.  Here is my code:

```js
  var dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");
  var dropzone2 = document.getElementById("dropzone2");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  var dragging = null;
  var wheredrop = null;

  function dragover(e){
      wheredrop = e.target;
  }

  function dragend(e){
      wheredrop.appendChild(dragging);
      wheredrop = null;
      dragging = null;
  }

  function drag(e){
      dragging = e.target;
  }

  text.ondragstart = drag;
  text.ondragend = dragend;
  dropzone.ondragenter = dragover;
  dropzone2.ondragenter = dragover;
  document.body.ondragenter = dragover;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Drag</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dropzone" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 49.85%; height: 300px; float: left; margin-top: -50px;"></div>
        <div id="dropzone2" style="border: 1px solid green; width: 49.85%; height: 300px; float: right; margin-top: -50px;"></div>
        <p id="text" draggable="true" style="border: 1px solid pink; margin-top: 150px;">This is text to drag.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a property into your styles `display:inline-block` .I think it will solve both your issue it will be below div and the border of p would only take the size of the text

Comment: Thank you so much! Why does this work, though??

Comment: You could also wrap your divs in a flex parent element, wrapping that parent and the p element in another parent element and make its flex direction column. Also remove the IDs of the divs and add classes. Then just querySelectorAll in the JS for the div elements. This would also allow you to remove the float as well.

Comment: You should add a solid border to your body element and watch what happens to it when you drag that thing around.  It's a bit of a mess.

Comment: It works because the block property makes it cover the width of the page so pushing it to next line and inline property makes it to cover the size of the width.So inline-block is a mix of both .You can refer more at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by clearing the float. Add this `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` between second/last `div` and `p` element. This will clear the effect of float after the divs.

```
<div id="dropzone" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 49.85%; height: 300px; float: left; margin-top: -50px;"></div>
<div id="dropzone2" style="border: 1px solid green; width: 49.85%; height: 300px; float: right; margin-top: -50px;"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<p id="text" draggable="true" style="border: 1px solid pink; margin-top: 150px;">This is text to drag.</p>
```